# My live data is getting updated but doesn't trigger the observer in android kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have a livedata variable which I keep listening from my main activity for possible changes to do some operations in the UI thread, but unfortunately it isn't getting triggered. And please note the method test() is being called from the Javascript interface which is used for webview communication.

This is what I have implemented,

```
class MainViewModel(){
.
.
.

 var data = MutableLiveData<String>();

 fun test(value: String){
     data.value = DataProtocol(
             "sample",
             arrayOf("CONNECTED")).toString()
    }
}
```

This was my first attempt but I am getting an error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke setValue on a
> background thread

Next i tried doing this,

```
 fun test(value: String){
  data.postValue(DataProtocol(
                     "sample",
                    arrayOf("CONNECTED")).toString())
}
```

Still no updates, then I tried it this way,

```
fun test(value: String){
 viewModelScope.launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
      data.postValue(DataProtocol(
                         "sample",
                        arrayOf("CONNECTED")).toString())
      }
  }
}
```

And finally I am out of options.

This is how I am listening it from the main activity

```
this.viewModel.data.observe(this) { d ->
   println("RECIEVED DATA " + d)
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong. I really want to get this triggered from the main activity but no idea why this isn't working. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you log instead of using `println`? We typically aren’t looking at console output when testing an Android app, only LogCat.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I tried logging but no luck

Comment: I can’t spot the problem but I see that isn’t your actual code since it isn’t compileable (can’t have a function parameter named `val`). You might have modified something when posting here that is hiding your error.

Comment: @Tenfour04 please check now I updated the code. I had to remove some logic inside those methods because it's confidential

Comment: You made `data` a `var` instead of `val`. Are you changing the  value stored in the property, because that could cause your issue if you're observing a different instance. I can't think of any good reason to put a LiveData in a `var` property. Did you try logging from your `test()` function to be sure it's actually called?

Comment: Where do you call `observe` and where do you call the `test` method?

Answer (score 0):

You attached incomplete parts of your code, so it's difficult to detect the problem you're facing from these snippets.

However, I've written some working code for you, so you can compare it with yours to identify the problem. Hope it will help.

Here is the working code:

MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.test

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     private val viewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        viewModel.text.observe(this) { text ->
            Log.i("TestLog", text)
        }

        viewModel.updateText("New text")
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.kt:

```
package com.example.test

import androidx.annotation.MainThread
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val text = MutableLiveData<String>("Initial value")

    @MainThread
    fun updateText(value: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            updateTextInWorkerThread(value)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun updateTextInWorkerThread(value: String) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            text.value = value
        }
    }

}
```

As a result, in Logs there are displayed 2 strings:

```
2023-04-26 12:52:37.440  7773-7773  TestLog                 com.example.test                     I  Initial value
2023-04-26 12:52:37.532  7773-7773  TestLog                 com.example.test                     I  New text
```